# Excluding IPs from analytics, but keeping personalization.

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, personalization

I want to exclude some groups of internal users from analytics, but keep the website personalized for them (and gather data for future personalization).

I tried 2 approaches and none of them worked:

- Exclude Robots - exclude from analytics but personalization stops working.
- aggregation.filter.inbound -  I created a custom processor in which I set `args.IsExcluded = true`  when IP is on a list. This doesn't work as the data still shows in Analytics Reports, even when the logs says that the filter was called and it should be filtered out.

What I want to try:

- set `Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactSaveMode = ContactSaveMode.NeverSave;` in a pipelines after the tracker is created when IP is internal. But as I understand that will stop gathering data for contact.
- add custom processor to `interactions` pipeline that will abort the pipelines when internal IP is used in interaction. I'm not sure if this will work and how to get interaction IP here.
- creating a custom channel for internal users, and adding a filter by channel to each of Analytics Reports. I am not sure if all reports can be filtered by channel.

Comment: Can you try to add the IP within the config file `Sitecore.Analytics.ExcludeRobots.config` and see if it fixes the problem

Comment: As mentioned in the post, using exclude robots don't solve the problem as it shut down the personalization for the user. And i still want to personalize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I went with creating a custom chanel for internal users and then filtering out the internal traffic from reports via the rule engine.

So the rough steps to follow are as follows:

1. Create a new chanel in Sitecore and copy it's id.
   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/digital_marketing/marketing_operations/channels/create_a_channel
2. Make Sitecore recognize your new chanel.
   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/digital_marketing/marketing_operations/channels/map_traffic_types_to_channels
3. Write a new processor inherit from `DetermineChannelProcessorBase`.

   ```
   namespace Custom.Pipelines.DetermineInteractionChannel
   {
       public class InternalTrafficChannel : DetermineChannelProcessorBase
       {

           private readonly string channelId;

           protected readonly List<string> Filters = new List<string>();

           public virtual void AddFilter(string filter)
           {
               if (this.Filters.Contains(filter))
                   return;
               this.Filters.Add(filter);
           }

           public InternalTrafficChannel(string channelId)
           {
               this.channelId = channelId;
           }

           public override void Process(DetermineChannelProcessorArgs args)
           {
               if (IsInternalTraffic(args.Interaction))
               {
                   args.ChannelId = new ID(this.channelId);
               }
           }

           private bool IsInternalTraffic(CurrentInteraction interaction)
           {
           \\write your logic here.
           }        
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the new processor to `determineInteractionChannel` pipeline.

   ```
   <sitecore>
       <pipelines>
       <determineInteractionChannel>
           <processor type="Custom.Pipelines.DetermineInteractionChannel.InternalTrafficChannel, Custom.Pipelines">
           <param desc="channelId">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</param>
           <filters hint="list:AddFilter">
               <filter>127.0.0.1</filter>
           </filters>
           </processor>
       </determineInteractionChannel>
       </pipelines>
   </sitecore>
   ```
5. Create a filter to exclude internal users in `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Experience Analytics/Filters` and as a rule write:

   ```
   Rule 1
   except when the current interaction is on the Internal channel
   add visit to segment
   Rule 2
   except when the current interaction is on a channel in the Internal channel group
   add visit to segment
   ```
6. Amend Segments that you are interested in to use the new filter.
7. Rebuild your reporting db.
   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/walkthrough_rebuilding_the_reporting_database